# classes and objects in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have defined a class like this:

```
class classname:
    def funname(self,idno,door):
        self.idno = 120
        self.door = 150
```

Then, created an object:

```
obj = classname()
```

While accessing the variables of that object (obj) like this `obj.funname()` I am getting an error:

```
TypeError: funname() takes exactly 3 arguments (1 given)
```

But, `obj.funname(4,5)` is working fine

I have already assigned values to variables in class. Why then should I pass the arguments again? Even if I pass the values, values are not changing.

```
>>>obj.idno
120
>>>obj.door
150
```

Then what is the point of passing them?

Comment: Indeed, if you're not going to use your arguments, then don't write your function to accept them!

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Looks to me like you wanted to define the function as `def funname(self):`

Comment: @DavidRobinson then I won't be able use idno,addr variables inside the class

Comment: You already have them hardcoded as `self.idno = 120` and `self.door = 150`, not the values you're passing- so it makes no difference. You can still do `self.door` in the class- it will always be equal to 150.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to leave those values always set, do something like this:

```
class ClassName:
    def funname(self):
        self.idno = 120
        self.door = 150
```

Now, if what you want is to have default values, do this:

```
class ClassName:
    def funname(self, idno=120, door=150):
        self.idno = idno
        self.door = door
```

Answer (score 3):

I think what you want is to create an `__init__` funciton to pass in your idno and door, like:

```
def __init__(self, idno, door):
    self.idno = idno
    self.door = door
```

Now, when you create a new object you pass in those values and they'll be stored:

```
foo = classname(120, 150)
```

Then later in some function you can access them:

```
def printStuff(self):
    print("My idno is {} and my door is {}".format(self.idno, self.door))
```

And do like:

```
foo.printStuff()
```

Which will output:

```
"My idno is 120 and my dooor is 150"
```

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use optional arguments or remove them.

```
class classname:
   def funname(self, idno = 120, door = 150):
      self.idno = idno
      self.door = door
```

OR

```
class classname:
   def funname(self):
      self.idno = 120
      self.door = 150
```